# How to copy files by hard linking when dereferencing symlinks (to extract files from git annex)

Tags: linux, git, file-transfer, rsync, git-annex

I'm experimenting with [git annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/), and before I import too much to git annex I'd like to figure out how to quickly blow away the "annexed" git repository without losing my annexed file content and its directory structure.  All "annexed" files are actually symlinks into `.git/annex/objects`, like this:

```
$ git init
Initialised empty Git repository in /tmp/annex/.git/
$ git annex init
init  ok
(recording state in git...)
$ touch foo
$ git annex add foo
add foo ok
(recording state in git...)
$ git commit -a
[master (root-commit) 609a6df] Initial
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 120000 foo
$ ls -l foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 178 Jan  6 15:10 foo -> .git/annex/objects/pX/ZJ/SHA256E-s0--e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855/SHA256E-s0--e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

So simply removing the .git directory would also remove all the actual file content!

What I want is a command to take an annexed repository like that above and create a new directory containing just the (unsymlinked) files: in this case, just the single file `foo`.  To save space until I remove the original annex directory, I want the file `foo` to be a hard link to `.git/annex/objects/pX/ZJ/SHA256E-s0--e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855/SHA256E-s0--e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855` (obviously in a realistic example, there would be many files in the repository).

git annex's own commands for "unannexing" (such as `git annex uninit`) are limited: in particular they do not well support quickly turning a git annex repository into a plain directory of files.  That motivates the following problem:

How can I copy a directory of files, de-referencing symlinks, but hard linking to the referents of the symlinks?

I tried `rsync`'s `--link-dest`, like this:

```
rsync -rLptgoD --safe-links --exclude='.git/' --link-dest=annex annex/ copy
```

But that doesn't produce hard links, presumably because the presence of the symlinks means that rsync doesn't know which files to hard link to.

Answer (score 0):

> git annex's own commands for "unannexing" (such as `git annex uninit`) are limited: in particular they do not well support quickly turning a git annex repository into a plain directory of files.

That sounds incorrect. The command operates recursively, so you can just run `git annex unannex .` while being at the root of your repository, and all files will be extracted.

But in a v5 format git-annex repository, you have another option: Switch to "direct" mode using `git annex direct`. This moves all files out of the object store and exposes them directly, without links. This command converts the entire working tree at once.

The files still remain tracked by git-annex; v5 direct mode merely changes how the local checkout is done, so it may be the fastest method because it doesn't actually write new data into Git.

So if you want to *clone* the whole file tree, you can 1) switch the repository to "direct" mode; 2) hardlink all files using rsync (excluding .git entirely); 3) if desired, switch the original repository to "indirect" mode again.

Alternatively, after switching to direct mode, simply remove the `.git` folder...

Comment: I'm using version 7 because I want to start with what will presumably be the future of git annex.  Joey says here that `uninit` is slow in part because of running `git rm --cached` for every file: https://git-annex.branchable.com/git-annex-uninit/ , and I see from the code and an strace test that `unannex` does the same.

Comment: As far as I know, v7-format repositories don't actually have the kind of symlinks that you show? The git-annex version may be 7.x, but the repo still looks like v5 to me.

Comment: v7 format repos do use symlinks just like that, yes.  It only doesn't use symlinks if you git add directly (`git add` as opposed to `git annex add`).  I didn't show the upgrade in the example because I added that example for people who don't know git annex, just to explain the idea (or at least, if I'd given it any thought, that would have been the reason ;-).

Answer (score 0):

This will quickly copy the files while (sort of) preserving permissions, ownership, timestamps, and hard linking so as not to use more space (as long as the copy is on the same filesystem):

`cp -rLlp annex copy`

It surprises me that rsync isn't able to replicate this behaviour, but as far as I can tell, it can't.

Three issues with the cp solution:

1. Any non-annexed symlinks that are either untracked or checked in to git directly will be replaced with whatever files they point to (but I suspect I won't have any).  Before I realized I could just use `cp`, I wrote a Python program that uses `os.walk` to copy one file at a time: since that knows about git annex, it gets this correct: it runs `rsync -ptgo --dirs` to copy directories and `cp -Ll` and `cp -Pl` on non-directory annexed files and other non-directory files respectively (the program is entangled a bit with utility code and not carefully tested so I won't post it here).
2. Though `cp` preserves permissions, those files may be "locked", meaning they are in their symlinked, uneditable state.  For that reason, writeable files will end up non-writeable in the copy.  Using `git annex unlock .` instead of `cp` will avoid that problem (this is for git annex repo format v6 / v7 -- for earlier formats I believe you can switch to direct mode instead of unlocking).
3. You'll end up with a copy of the `.git` directory inside directory `copy`, containing more hard-linked copies of the same files.  Again that takes up no more space because of the hard links, and you can just `sudo rm -rf .git` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer (run this at the top level directory of the repository):

```
git annex unlock .
```

Advantages:

- Permissions are preserved (see my other answer).
- Untracked and already-unlocked symlinks are preserved (again, see my other answer).
- Running strace shows that at least the slowness issue Joey Hess dignoses in [a comment here](https://git-annex.branchable.com/git-annex-uninit/) as affecting `git annex uninit` (which also applies to `git annex unannex .`) does not affect this command.  I don't know how fast it is for realistic repositories, though: I'm just doing pre-emptive testing here.

Disadvantages:

- Unless you're using a filesystem like btrfs for which GNU cp supports copy-on-write, git annex will copy every file (you'll end up with each annexed file under both `.git` and as a regular file in the working copy).  I think that still shouldn't be unreasonably slow, but will take up disk space.